# Modify current source using lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets assume that I have an `IEnumerable<MyType>` called `myList`. I would like to remove some items from the list using a lambda expression.

Currently, I do it in the following way:

```
myList = myList.Where(x=>x.SomeProp == 1);
```

I would like to do something like:

```
myList.Remove(x=>x.SomeProp != 1);
```

I know that `Remove()` doesn't exist by default, but does a similar method exist? Or do I have to write an extension method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking a Remove operation on an IEnumerable would achieve...? Just another way to write a `Where` with an inverted condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` itself doesn't expose any mutating operations - so you *can't* expose a `Remove` operation. If you're trying to remove items from a `List<T>` you could use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) though.

If you want a sort of "inverse where" which excluded rather than included items, then you could write that very easily. It's not clear that it would really be advantageous to do so though - you can usually invert the logic of a predicate very easily, and while `Where` is familiar to other programmers, your new extension method wouldn't be.

I definitely *wouldn't* call such an operation `Remove` though - that sounds like it's a mutating operation. I'd probably call it something like `ExceptWhere` - so you'd have:

```
var adults = people.ExceptWhere(person => person.Age < 18);
```

as an example.

Comment: Based on this, it sounds like `myList.ToList().RemoveAll(x=>x.SomeProp != 1)` is what I'm after.

Comment: I'd prefer `Where` with a flipped predicate over that. Easier to read, less code, and more efficient to boot.

Comment: @MattGreer Do you really think it's easier to read? The only difference would be that the removeall() epxression would be the negation of the where(), right? And what do you mean by "more efficent to boot"?

Comment: @Johan: Except that `RemoveAll` returns an `int`. So you'd have to declare a separate variable and assign the list to it, then use `RemoveAll` on that variable. As for the efficiency - if you don't need to copy all the data to another list, why do so?

Comment: @Johan I do think it's easier to read. People are very used to LINQ's `Where`, and you have to stop and wonder why the `ToList()` is needed, which isn't immediately obvious. The `ToList()` dumps the enumerable into a new List object, so your approach creates an additional object and does two iterations instead of one.